# duda con modelo de base de datos relacional

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, diagrama-er

Muy buenas tardes, actualmente me encuentro diagramando una DB-R para mi proyecto de grado, en la cual debo guardar los datos de los empleados de una oficina.

**Los datos a guardar son los siguientes:**

•   Nombre

•   Apellido

•   Sexo

•   Ci (campo único)

•   fecha de nacimiento

•   N° de cargo (campo único)

•   Fecha de ingreso

•   Email (campo único)

•   Estatus (contratado, fijo, abandono de cargo, destituido)

•   Su cargo

•   Su ubicación administrativa

•   Nomina a la que pertenecen

•   Sus jefes.

Condiciones para diagramar:

1. Un empleado pertenece a una sola nómina.
2. Un empleado puede o no tener un ascenso (cambio de cargo) en un lapso de tiempo, así como también puede estar sin un cargo.
3. La ubicación administrativa del empleado puede o no cambiar y hay que tener registro del cambio. Puede darse el caso de no tener una ubicación.
4. Hay cargos que dependen de una ubicación administrativa y otros que no.
   **Ejem.** 
   •   El cargo de **jefe de oficina** pertenece la ubicación administrativa de **Jefatura**, **jefe de RRHH** a **RRHH**, **coord. Afiliación** a Sección de **afiliación**, etc. Los cuales son cargos que identifican a los jefes y tienes que estar relacionados obligatoriamente con la ubicación administrativa a la que pertenecen, por lo tanto, el empleado que tenga el cargo de jefe de oficina no puede estar ubicado en RRHH.

**NOTA: No puede haber mas de un empleado con el mismo cargo de jefe.**

•   Los cargos de asistente administrativo (**I**, **II**, **III**, **IV**, **IV**) son cargos que no dependen de la ubicación administrativa por lo tanto se pueden rotar a los empleados por las distintas ubicaciones y que se mantenga el cargo del empleado.

5. Un empleado puede o no tener jefes.
6. Un jefe puede tener uno o varios jefes.
7. Ciertas ubicaciones administrativas tienen cargos de jefes por lo tanto el empleado que tenga ese cargo será el jefe de todo aquel que este ubicado en ella.
8. Se debe tener un registro de todos los jefes actuales de cada ubicación administrativa que tenga cargos de jefes.
9. Se debe tener un registro de todos los empleados que han pasado por un cargo de jefe en específico.

Después de leer esto diagrame siguiendo lo antes expuesto, pero no estoy seguro si cumplo con todo lo que esta allí, no se si las relaciones estén correctas y tengo muchas dudas y por eso acudo a ustedes.

En total fueron 6 tablas.

El diagrama :

[image: Diagrama de la base de datos de la que hablaba]

---

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `empleados` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
```

---

```
USE `empleados` ;
```

---

-- Table `empleados`.`nominas`

---

aquí guardo los nombres de todas las nominas con las que se trabajan

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empleados`.`nominas` (

  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `empleados`.`empleados`

---

aquí guardo los datos del los empleados.

- el campo **nomonas_id** lo uso para especificar a que nomina
  pertenece el empleado.
- el campo **empleados_jefe_id** lo uso para especificar el id del empleado con cargo de jefe , este campo puede ir nulo en caso de no tener jefe.

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empleados`.`empleados` (

  `id` INT NOT NULL,

  `nominas_id` INT NOT NULL,

  `empleados_jefe_id` INT NULL,

  `fecha_nacimiento` DATE NOT NULL,

  `ci` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  `apellido` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  `sexo` ENUM('masculino', 'femenino') NOT NULL,

  `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  `fecha_ingreso` DATE NOT NULL,

  `estatus` ENUM('contratado', 'fijo', 'destituido', 'abandono') NOT NULL,

  `n_cargo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  UNIQUE INDEX `ci_UNIQUE` (`ci` ASC),

  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),

  UNIQUE INDEX `n_cargo_UNIQUE` (`n_cargo` ASC),

  INDEX `fk_empleados_nominas_idx` (`nominas_id` ASC),

  INDEX `fk_empleados_empleados1_idx` (`empleados_jefe_id`

  ASC),

  CONSTRAINT `fk_empleados_nominas`

  ```
  FOREIGN KEY (`nominas_id`)

  REFERENCES `mydb`.`nominas` (`id`)

  ON DELETE NO ACTION

  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ```

  CONSTRAINT `fk_empleados_empleados1`

  ```
  FOREIGN KEY (`empleados_jefe_id`)

  REFERENCES `mydb`.`empleados` (`id`)

  ON DELETE NO ACTION

  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  ```

  )ENGINE = InnoDB;

  ---

  -- Table `empleados`.`ubicacion_administrativa`

  ---

Aqui guardo todas las ubicaciones administrativas que hay dentro de la oficina

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`ubicacion_administrativa` (

     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

     `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

     UNIQUE INDEX `nombre_UNIQUE` (`nombre` ASC)
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `empleados`.`cargos`

---

Aquí guardo todos los cargos que se manejan dentro de la oficina

- El campo **ubicacion_administrativa_id** lo uso para especificar que ese cargo pertenece a una ubicación administrativa. Este campo puede ir nulo para separar los cargos que no dependen de una ubicación.
- El campo **jefe_coord** lo uso para especificar a la hora de registrar el el cargo si es un cargo con condición de jefe o no

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empleados`.`cargos` (

  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `ubicacion_administrativa_id` INT NULL,

  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  `jefe_coord` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  INDEX `fk_cargos_ubicacion_administrativa1_idx` 
  (`ubicacion_administrativa_id` ASC),

  CONSTRAINT `fk_cargos_ubicacion_administrativa1`

  ```
  FOREIGN KEY (`ubicacion_administrativa_id`)

  REFERENCES `mydb`.`ubicacion_administrativa` (`id`)

  ON DELETE NO ACTION

  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  ```

  )ENGINE = InnoDB;

---

-- Table `empleados`.`cargos_empleados`

---

Esta tabla la uso como un historial , en ella guardo todos los cargos que ha tenido el empleado, ademas me permite sacar los empleados con cargos de jefes actuales si selecciono los últimos.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empleados`.`cargos_empleados` (

     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

     `empleados_id` INT NOT NULL,

     `cargos_id` INT NOT NULL,

     `fecha_cambio` DATE NOT NULL,

     INDEX `fk_cargos_empleados_empleados1_idx` (`empleados_id` ASC),

     INDEX `fk_cargos_empleados_cargos1_idx` (`cargos_id` ASC),

     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

     CONSTRAINT `fk_cargos_empleados_empleados1`

       FOREIGN KEY (`empleados_id`)

       REFERENCES `mydb`.`empleados` (`id`)

       ON DELETE NO ACTION

       ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

     CONSTRAINT `fk_cargos_empleados_cargos1`

       FOREIGN KEY (`cargos_id`)

       REFERENCES `mydb`.`cargos` (`id`)

       ON DELETE NO ACTION

       ON UPDATE NO ACTION

    )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `empleados`.`empleados_ubicacion_administrativa`

---

esta taba la uso como historial

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empleados`.`empleados_ubicacion_administrativa` (

     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

      `empleados_id` INT NOT NULL,

      `ubicacion_administrativa_id` INT NOT NULL,

      `fecha_cambio` DATE NOT NULL,

      INDEX 

    `fk_empleados_ubicacion_administrativa_ubicacion_administrat_i

    dx` (`ubicacion_administrativa_id` ASC),

      INDEX `fk_empleados_ubicacion_administrativa_empleados1_idx` 

    (`empleados_id` ASC),

      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

      CONSTRAINT 

    `fk_empleados_ubicacion_administrativa_empleados1`

        FOREIGN KEY (`empleados_id`)

        REFERENCES `mydb`.`empleados` (`id`)

        ON DELETE NO ACTION

        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

      CONSTRAINT 

    `fk_empleados_ubicacion_administrativa_ubicacion_administrativa1`

        FOREIGN KEY (`ubicacion_administrativa_id`)

        REFERENCES `mydb`.`ubicacion_administrativa` (`id`)

        ON DELETE NO ACTION

        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    )ENGINE = InnoDB;



  SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
    SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

las dudas que tengo son con lo de los jefes y con lo de los cargos de jefes que están relacionados a una ubicación administrativa.

para lo de los jefes estoy relacionando la tabla empleados con ella misma en una relación uno a muchos y estoy permitiendo que la llave foránea pueda ir nula para que se pueda dar el caso de no tener jefe.

para el historial de los jefes lo puedo sacar con la tabla de cargos , estoy definiendo un campo jefe de tipo bool que permitira especificar a la hora de registrar el cargo si es un cargo de jefe o no, ademas también tiene una llave foranea de ubicacion_administrativa que puede ir nula para separar los cargos que tienen relaciones con la ubicación y los que no. Esto me permite tener un historial de quienes tuvieron el cargo en una especie de historial y el actual seleccionando el ultmo.

Comment: Creo que ayudaría mucho si nos dices las dudas que tienes y si nos dices también al lado de cada requerimiento, brevemente, cómo lo has resuelto. Por ejemplo: **Un empleado puede o no tener jefes:** *he hecho esto para satisfacer ese requisito*  ... **Se debe tener un registro de todos los jefes actuales de cada ubicación administrativa que tenga cargos de jefes.** *he declarado el campo tal en tabla tal y el campo tal en tabla tal para satisfacer este requisito*. Eso no solo nos ayudará a nosotros a ayudarte sino a ti también a documentar tu diseño y a detectar posibles lagunas en el mismo.

Comment: Definitivamente cual es el problema de tu diseño? aclara eso por favor, así podremos ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Por qué 2 tablas relacionadas a los cargos?

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder! les especifique un poco mas lo que hago con las tablas en contenido del post . Mi problema es que no se si el diagrama cumple con lo antes expuesto, por eso acudo a ustedes. El mayor inconveniente lo tengo con los jefes y los cargos que tienen relación con una ubicación.

Comment: Tu nueva edición, según mi criterio, no ayuda a comprender el problema. Estaba mejor planteada antes, pero **faltaba poner al lado de cada cosa un pequeño comentario de cómo lo resolviste**. El problema es que la pregunta es amplia y tal como lo has planteado ahora obliga a meterse a analizar el modelo de datos completo lo cual no es evidente. Creo que si nos permites leer los requerimientos poniendo al lado cómo los has resuelto y al final pones el modelo de datos como lo tenías la comprensión es mejor. Ahora está todo más disperso y para entenderlo hay que intentar meterse 100% en el modelo.

Comment: Tratare de redactar mejor el post detallando mis dudas y mañana la publicare . Tomare en cuenta todo lo que me comentaron para que se les haga mas entendible . Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anon... Esta pregunta es SÚPER AMPLIA. Básicamente nos pides hagamos el análisis por ti.

Si hay algo en lo que te puedo ayudar, es en lo siguiente:

**Restricciones** (*Domain Constraint*, porque pertenecen a *Negocio*): Las restricciones que planteas en tu ejercicio son simples, sin embargo, cuando son mucho más complejas es tentador utilizar la base de datos para obligar el cumplimiento de estas reglas, pero te regalo un consejo: (no está escrito en piedra,
personalmente lo recomiendo):

**La base de datos no debería contener lógica de negocios**. La base de datos es para guardar información, no para controlar la validez de esta lógica. Para eso, justamente, existe una capa llamada *Lógica de Negocios* en muchas arquitecturas. Hay restricciones que **NO PERTENECEN A LA BASE DE DATOS**. Por lo tanto, no es *responsabilidad* del RDBMS (motor de base de datos) verificar su cumplimiento.

Dicho esto, **tienes ciertas restricciones que sí pueden ser manejadas desde la base de datos**.

Vamos por puntos:

1. Tu diagrama claramente tiene una referencia circular. Necesitas cambiar las relaciones: (**Empleados -> Cargos_Empleados -> cargos -> ubicacion_administrativa -> empleados_ubicacion_administrativa-> Empleados**). Tu diagrama me dice que un empleado puede tener muchos cargos. A través del tiempo sí. Pero no hay una columna que me diga si el cargo está activo o no. FechaCambio no es muy descriptivo que digamos.

Mi opinión es que la tabla *empleados_ubicacion_administrativa* no debería existir. Un empleado tiene varios cargos y un cargo tiene una ubicación administrativa; de esa manera obtienes la ubicación administrativa de un empleado. Tu diagrama nos dice que:
**Un empleado puede tener una ubicación administrativa sin tener un cargo**. No lo considero correcto.

2. La restricción

> el empleado que tenga el cargo de jefe de oficina no puede estar ubicado en RRHH.

Me sugiere que debería existir un campo *esJefatura bool* en la tabla cargo... Pero también puede que haya **sólo un gerente por departamento**. Por lo tanto, si queremos que el sistema sea escalable, **yo** tendría una relación *tipo_cargo* en lugar de "esJefatura".

Por qué? Porque así, la relación EMPLEADO-TIPO_CARGO-UBICACIÓN_ADMINISTRATIVA es más fácil de controlar. No puedo tener dos empleados que son jefes dentro de la misma ubicación administrativa, así como no puedo tener dos gerentes en una misma ubicación administrativa, pero sí te permite tener 23 asistentes a gerente. **PERO el cumplimiento de esta regla SE DEBERÍA MANEJAR EN LA CAPA DE LÓGICA DE NEGOCIOS**. No es responsabilidad de la base de datos.

3. La decisión de referenciar la tabla empleados con ella misma, es acertada.
4. Para el historial... Sugiero las columnas FechaInicio,  FechaFinal y "activo" (si lo deseas) en la tabla empleado_cargo para que se haga más fácil el control y el historial.
5. n_cargo **no debería** estar en la tabla empleado. Según la segunda forma normal, **LOS DATOS EN LA COLUMNA DEBEN DEPENDER ÚNICA Y EXCLUSIVAMENTE DE LA LLAVE PRIMARIA**. El nombre del cargo no depende del empleado, sino del cargo mismo.

Hay MUCHÍSIMAS reglas que no pueden ser implementadas a través de la base de datos. De forma abstracta, se puede decir que la BD es responsable únicamente de guardar y extraer información, Create-Recover/Retrieve-Update-Delete (CRUD).

Tu pregunta es muy amplia y sujeta a opiniones... Esta respuesta es una de ellas. Suerte

Comment: Si la pregunta es basada en opiniones entonces lo mejor es no responderla pues es casi seguro termine cerrada y tu aporte se pierda

Comment: No te adelantes a los acontecimientos. Tal vez alguna respuesta te ayude